# The igniters on my range are clicking without me actuating them

Tags: kitchens

Frigidaire range. I hear  the igniters clicking about every 30 seconds.

Why do the  burner igniters on my range try to light when I’m not using them?

---

M# fpg$3085kfc S# nfo1942381 Took a while to find it’s been along time since I’ve worked on appliances

---

That is odd after cleaning the moisture must cause the ground but I haven’t clean my oven in a while.

Comment: Mine does this after over aggressive cleaning, when the ceramic ignitor electrode and burner cover is damp. I don't understand it really, because the switches are open (i.e. off) and in my mind there should not be power there. But it does it regularly and consistently and stops when everything dries out. This is caused by a cohabitant whom I will not name who I love but am loath to criticize publicly; plus at least she cleans it...

Comment: What model is your range?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it That it only occurs after "aggressive cleaning" and stops when "everything dries out" suggests that things are wet and that water is somehow compromising the separation between the two sides of the switching circuit, either at or within one of the switches, or between the two wire branches. This would allow some current to leak from one side of the circuit to the other, and thus enable the ignitor.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, yes I figure the moisture is acting as a "jumper" of sorts, but it still doesn't jive because the control knobs (which open or close the ignitor circuit) are nowhere near the damp components and do not themselves get wet. Sooo... it's a mystery to me, but doesn't bother me enough to have me investigating more thoroughly.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I replaced one of the burner gas valves in our stove a few weeks ago, and was surprised to see how far that valve's ignitor switch was from the knob. If one is cleaning the stove top and the burner area, maybe that's close enough to impact the system's integrity. I agree that "Doesn't bother me enough" is often a very appropriate disposition.

Comment: You seem to indicate that this has happened after cleaning, but that you haven't cleaned recently. Where I am, it's gotten very rainy over the last couple of days and the humidity is through the roof. If the humidity has gone up where you are, it may be enough to provide a conductor that's causing your igniters to spark. In either case, it seems like it would be worthwhile tracing the wiring looking for the slightest damage in wiring and replace anything that could be bad. It will only get worse.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be a `$` in the model number or should it be an `S` or a `4`?

Answer (score 0):

When operating correctly, an electrical circuit supplies power to the ignitor system when a burner valve is turned on. This circuit usually consists of parallel connections to individual switches, with one switch mounted on each burner valve. If the oven is also heated by gas, there'll be a switch on the oven valve as well.

In your appliance, there's a flaw in the circuit and power is being provided when no burner (or oven) valve is actuated. This could be a short circuit between the wiring that carries the two sides of the circuit, or a valve switch may have failed closed, thus allowing the ignitor to be energized even though the user hasn't turned a valve on.